# how to hide the url variable from url in pagereference?

Tags: apex, visualforce

i want to hide the url value from the url,here is my code

```
string st = lowesPortalTranscations[0].Store_Number__c;
                        system.debug(st);
                            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/StoreNumAssistance?str='+st);
                            pageRef.getParameters().put('str',lowesPortalTranscations[0].Store_Number__c);
                            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                            return pageRef;
```

i am getting the url like this

```
StoreNumAssistance?str=1440
```

i want to hide the value str=1440

i didn't understand how to do it,please help me?

Comment: Additionally, if I cannot hide it for whatever reason, I encrypt it and decrypt in the controller of the receiving page

Comment: how i will encrypt and decrypt it?

Comment: A quick search on "encrypt parameter" brought this up: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=encrypt+parameter - Take you pick